# ASP.NET - Simple code-behind variable with Syntax Error

Tags: asp.net, .net

In my aspx code I have something like this

```
if(AnId == <%=MyCodebehindObject.MyId%>)
{
    // stuff
}
```

The code is working: I can get the value from the codebehind variable. However, I'm getting a "Syntax error" warning right at the end of the first line.

I can "fixed it" by enclosing the variable with quotes, but this will make my variable a string, and I'm expecting an int. That will work just fine, the javascript will cast it for comparison, but I think that is just stupid and I was trying to find the write way of doing it.

Any ideas?

Comment: is if the if statement javascript?

Comment: yes, the if is a javascript statement

Comment: ok, thanks, you need to wrap the codebehind in quotes see my answer

Comment: `MyCodebehindObject.MyID` What is this..? any Control's ID..?

Comment: No. It's the page codebehind object, where the codebehind variable vives.

Answer (score 3):

you need to wrap the javascript code behind in quotes

```
if(AnId == '<%= MyCodebehindObject.MyID%>'){
    // stuff
}
```

Comment: I noticed that, I was just wondering if there wasn't a way of not doing that, since I see no point of making my variable a string to later on compare it with an int.

Comment: perhaps I am not understanding what you're asking.  What is giving you the syntax error,  The Javascript console or the .net?

Comment: The .net is, the visual studio in the "Error List" window.